# How to compare date in python? I have a month date year format and want to compare to the current date (within 7 days)

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

This is the data that is being returned from my API:

```
"Jun 02, 2021, 2 PMEST"
```

If I'm within 7 days of the current date which I'm getting by doing this:

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
print("Today's date:", today)
```

Just need to convert Jun to a number and 02 and compare to see if it's within 7 days in the future of the current date, then return True

Answer (score 1):

**APPROACH 0:**

Given the format of your example data, you should be able to convert it to a `datetime` using this code:

```
datetime.strptime("Jun 02, 2021, 2 PMEST", "%b %d, %Y, %I %p%Z")
```

The details about this format string are here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

However, when I tested this locally, it worked for this input:

```
"Jun 02, 2021, 2 PMUTC"
```

but not for your input (which has different timezone):

```
"Jun 02, 2021, 2 PMEST"
```

I have investigated this some more and "read the docs" (https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html).
To get `EST` parsing to work, you would have to change your OS timezone and reset the `time` module's timezones like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import time

os.environ["TZ"] = "US/Eastern".  # change timezone
time.tzset().                     # reset time.tzname tuple
datetime.strptime("Jun 02, 2021, 2 PMEST", "%b %d, %Y, %I %p%Z")
```

When you're done, be safe and delete the "hacked" environment variable:

```
del os.environ["TZ"]
```

Note - Since your system timezone is presumably still `UTC`, it can still parse UTC timezone too.

See this thread for detailed discussion: https://bugs.python.org/issue22377

Also note that the timestamp is not actually captured. The result you get with `EST` and `UTC` is a naive datetime object.

**APPROACH 1**

So, it seems like there is a better way to approach this.
First, you need to `pip install dateutils` if you don't already have it.
THen do something like this:

```
from dateutil import parser
from dateutil.tz import gettz

tzinfos = {"EST": gettz("US/Eastern")}

my_datetime = parser.parse("Jun 02, 2021, 2 PM EST", tzinfos=tzinfos)
```

What's happening here is we use `gettz` to get timezone information from the timezones listed in `usr/share/zoneinfo`. Then the `parse` function can (fuzzy) parse your string (no format needs to be specified!) and returns `my_datetime` which has timezone information on it. Here are the parser docs: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html

I don't know how many different timezones you need to deal with so the rest is up to you. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah it didn't work for me either.  Only works for PMUTC.  Any solutions for "EST"?

Comment: I wrote a lot of stuff but the bit that should work for you is the last bit of code where I use the `dateutil` module.

Comment: approach #1 should be preferred, since you don't need to mess with package internals.

Comment: @MrFuppes I agree. I was just seeing how it "could" be done using the given libraries. I agree that the `dateutil.parser` approach is much much better.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date to a `datetime` structure and take the direct difference. Note that `today` must be a `datetime`, too.

```
import datetime
date_string = "Jun 02, 2021, 2 PMEST"
today = datetime.datetime.today()
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, 
                                  "%b %d, %Y, %I %p%Z") # Corrected
(date - today).days
#340
```

Comment: `%H` is incorrect. It would be used for, e.g. `14` hour.
From the docs: "Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number."

Comment: @PeacefulJames Agree.